# FreeBSD phantomJS installation issue

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, freebsd

After running command below

```
root@hz:/data/www/node # npm i phantomjs
```

I get

```
npm WARN deprecated phantomjs@2.1.3: Package renamed to phantomjs-prebuilt. Please update 'phantomjs' package references to 'phantomjs-prebuilt'

> phantomjs@2.1.3 install /data/www/node/node_modules/phantomjs
> node install.js

Looks like an `npm install -g`; unable to check for already installed version.
Downloading https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip
Saving to /data/www/node/node_modules/phantomjs/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip
Receiving...
  [=======================================-] 98%
Received 16746K total.
Extracting zip contents
Removing /data/www/node/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Copying extracted folder /data/www/node/node_modules/phantomjs/phantomjs/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip-extract-1454690434788/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx -> /data/www/node/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom
Writing location.js file
Done. Phantomjs binary available at /data/www/node/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs
npm ERR! FreeBSD 9.3-RELEASE
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "i" "phantomjs"
npm ERR! node v5.4.1
npm ERR! npm  v2.14.7
npm ERR! code EPEERINVALID

npm ERR! peerinvalid The package handlebars@4.0.2 does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /data/www/node/npm-debug.log
```

It seems phantomjs to be installed, but when i try to get phantomjs version

```
root@hz:/data/www/node # phantomjs --version
```

I get this

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/phantomjs: 1: Syntax error: Error in command substitution
root@hz:/data/www/node #
```

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? I need to run Node.JS server that should use phantom.JS, but whet it's expected to be in used I get next error

```
[Error: PhantomJS exited with return value 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You've run into a well-known bug of the node package manager / phantomjs's NPM package - it's installing the macosx version of phantomjs even though you're running FreeBSD:

> ```
> > phantomjs@2.1.3 install /data/www/node/node_modules/phantomjs
> > node install.js
> ...
> Downloading https://bitbucket.org/ariya/phantomjs/downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-macosx.zip
> ```

See this PhantomJS issue:

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/12963

Alternatively, you can install phantomjs from source; FreeBSD has a port to do that:

```
masheen(~) # cd /usr/ports/lang/phantomjs
masheen(~) # make install
```